# How to make mongoose's model.findByIdAndUpdate() trigger model.save()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model for users in my database. I have an update controller which calls the `findByIdAndUpdate` method on my model. Now, when I store passwords in my database I'd like to hash them first, so I have:

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function(next) {
  // if password is modified then hash it
  next();
});
```

Now when my update controller calls `findByIdAndUpdate` it seems to me that `model.save()` does not get called, so the hashing never happens.

Is there a way to overload the original behavior of `findByAndUpdate`, or what is a neat solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) triggers the [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) middleware.  Pre and post save() hooks are not executed on findOneAndUpdate().

You cannot access the document being updated in `pre('findOneAndUpdate')` middleware. 
If you need to access the document that will be updated, you need to execute an explicit query for the document.

Sample schema with findOneAndUpdate middleware:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

schema.pre("save", async function(next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) return next();
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
  next();
});

schema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function() {
  const docToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());

  // add your hashing logic to here
  let newPassword = await bcrypt.hash(docToUpdate.password, 12);

  this.set({ password: newPassword });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

Sample route to test:

```js
router.put("/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
  let result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {}, { new: true });

  res.send(result);
});
```

Note that I used {} inside findByIdAndUpdate, because our password will be hashed in `findOneAndUpdate` middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mongoose `findOneAndUpdate()` pre hook as below with comparison of new(incoming/updated) and previous(already in DB) values:

```
userSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function() {
  const docInDB = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());

  const newValues = (this as any)._update;

  //Add your password encryption/decryption logic as required
  if (docInDB.password && newValues.password && (docInDB.password !== newValues.password )) { 
      this.set({ password: newPassword });
  }
});
```